# Create a json literal from a yup schema?

Tags: javascript, yup

I can't find in the docs if it's possible to create a JSON literal from a yup schema like so:

```
let Person = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().required().positive().integer(),
  email: yup.string().email(),
  website: yup.string().url(),
  createdOn: yup.date().default(function () {
    return new Date();
  }),
});


const James = Person(req.body)
```

Does yup provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I must of missed it but schema.cast solves this.